# Get screenshot of linux machine using C++

Tags: c++, linux, screenshot, x11

I have a C++ program that takes the screenshot of my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. The program uses the X11 library. I need to execute this application from a daemon at boot time. But it returns `XOpenDisplay failed`. I think it is because the X11 server is not loaded. Is there any programmatic way by which I can get the screenshot soon after the X11 server is loaded?

EDIT:

Missed to tell something.. The daemon gets started at boot time and it fails to take screenshot. So after starting I stopped the daemon and started it again from terminal. The same error(XOpenDisplay failed) is shown then.. Is it a problem with screenshot and daemon??

Comment: A while loop that delays and tries again every 1000ms ?

Comment: Is the X server already running when the program is running and the `DISPLAY` environment variable correctly set?

Comment: Is it relevant, that the program is C++? If not, perhaps remove it from the title and the tags at least, to allow better audience for the question.

Comment: Anyway, you probably want to hook up to DBus to know when the desktop has loaded... Haven't tried, but I assume that's the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

It's not just a matter of waiting until the X server starts. To successfully connect to it:

- The X server must be running.
- The program must know its address to connect to it, which is typically stored in `DISPLAY` environmental variable.
- The program must authenticate to the X server, which is typically by giving X server cookie that was read from a file that is readable only to the user who is currently logged in.

All those conditions are fulfilled if you simply start the program as part of the graphical session, instead of starting it independently after boot.

There are several ways to achieve start of program inside the graphical session. One is by putting `something.desktop` file into `/etc/xdg/autostart` directory. You can check other files from there for syntax.

Comment: I tried adding the .desktop file. Though the call was success it returned no result. I tried writing the output to a binary file.. It is empty

Comment: Does it work correctly when run manually inside the graphical session? If yes,  then make sure you check for errors and you can log them to a file for debugging.

Comment: Manually from graphical session??can u explain it.. my application writes two files..error file and output file..both files are created..error file tells no error.but output file is empty

Comment: Just execute it from a terminal emulator, from your IDE or simply by double clicking it in some file browser. The point is to find out if the failure to take screenshot is caused by it being started from `/etc/xdg/autostart`, or if it just never works.

Comment: Can you please step by step tell how to execute it.. I have a `screenshot.desktop` file in `/etc/xdg/autostart` with the following content: 

`[Desktop Entry] Type=Application 

Encoding=UTF-8 
Version=1.0 
Name=screenshot 
Exec=/home/asd/eclipse_agent/bin/Screenshot 
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true 
X-KDE-autostart-after=panel`

Answer (score 2):

Add a script in [`/etc/X11/Xsession.d/`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man5/Xsession.5.html). The script will be run when X11 is running.

If you really need to start the daemon at boot, then what you could do, is send a [signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) from the script to the daemon process. You'll need to store the pid somewhere when you start the daemon.

```
kill -SIGUSR1 $PID
```

Then, your daemon should at the start [register a signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3817716/2079303) that will be called when the signal is received.

Taking a screen shot probably requires dynamic memory allocation though, and that's one of the things that you cannot do in a signal handler. So, what you will have to do, is have the daemon wait on a [condition variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) and have the signal handler set it and notify the waiter.

It would be much simpler to start the daemon after X11 starts, rather than at boot.

Comment: I added a simple script to run the application in Xsession.d. Will it be run automatically?

Comment: @Jackzz according to the manual: `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/
              is a directory containing Bourne shell scripts to be executed by
              Xsession.`